# Undefined method cast after update to Ecto 2.0

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I recently migrated to latest versions of phoenix and ecto.

Now I have changed code of a model, according to ecto changelog  to

```
defmodule Spaces.Tag do
  use Spaces.Web, :model
#Changed to below
defmodule Spaces.Tag do
  use Ecto.Schema
```

I am getting `(CompileError) web/models/tag.ex:23: undefined function cast/4.` Anything I am missing?

My mix.exs relevant code

```
  defp deps do
    [{:phoenix, "~> 1.2"},
     {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
     {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.0"},
     {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.6"},
     {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
     {:gettext, "~> 0.9"},
     {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
     {:httpoison, "~> 0.8.0"},
     {:jsx, "~> 2.8"},
     {:scrivener_ecto, "~> 1.0"},
     {:phoenix_html_simplified_helpers, "~> 0.4.0"},
     {:ex_doc, "~> 0.12.0", only: [:dev]}
    ]
  end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You also need to import certain modules:

```
  import Ecto
  import Ecto.Changeset # This is the one that includes cast
  import Ecto.Query
```

This was changed in Ecto 1.1 and was mentioned in http://www.phoenixframework.org/blog/upgrading-from-v10-to-v11#section-ecto-changes

You shouldn't need to do:

```
defmodule Spaces.Tag do
  use Spaces.Web, :model
#Changed to below
defmodule Spaces.Tag do
  use Ecto.Schema
```

Instead you should update `web.ex` to:

```
defmodule Spaces.Web do
  def model do
    quote do
      use Ecto.Schema

      import Ecto
      import Ecto.Changeset
      import Ecto.Query
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I rejected the edit here, please note this is the `model` function within `MyApp.Web` that is being defined.

Comment: Should all of my code be inside def model? I am now getting `undefined function schema`. Is there a tutorial of some sort that covers this entire thing?

Comment: You still need use `  use Spaces.Web, :model` inside of `Spaces.Tag` The tutorial is the upgrade guide I linked above.

Comment: thanks for your help, what version is the guide following.http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/overview. What I am getting at is, the documentation till now has been top notch, this is the first time I have ended up in a confusion

Comment: I am not sure what you are confused by. The guides that you linked are for reference/new applications. The upgrade guides are specifically for upgrading between phoenix versions. If you application is not working, please update your question with the error you are getting.

Comment: oops, I was looking into the wrong file, its clear now. I was assuming web.ex as my model file. Thanks for your help it's now clarified